# Ionic: clicking google maps marker to push page with NavController causes clicks on pushed page to not work

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework

After succesfully displaying the pushed page all elements with a (click)='doSomething()' bound to them do not work anywhere in the pushed page. The pushed page also has an ion-slides element, when sliding to a new slide all click events register at once (tried in browser and in android dev app). Refreshing the frame resolves the issue. Not sure if it's a bug or a problem in my code.

```
initMap() {
  let self = this;

  //other code is here to make map, init markers etc. all working fine

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',()=> {
    self.openPage();
  });
}
```

The function openPage:

```
openPage(){
  this.navCtrl.push(PlacefeedPage);
}
```

Noteworthy: if I call openPage from anywhere else it works 100% fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around for a bit longer I found the solution. For anyone running into this issue, the trick is to use NgZone (import it, declare in constructor), after that you can use:

```
self.ngZone.run(()=>{
    self.openPage();
 });
```